# Analytic map on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it true that for any two points $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1 \}$ there is an analytic map $f$ such that $f(-1)=z_1,f(1)=z_2$? 
From what I have read so far, I think it has to be some Möbius transformation $f(z) = \frac{z-w}{1-\overline{w}z}$ where $|w| < 1$. If this is true, then how can I find $w$?

$f$ is supposed to satisfy $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Mobius transformations send the boundary to the boundary so any such map is not Mobius.

Comment: are you sure you mean to take $\mathbb D$ to be the *closed* unit disk? if so, where should $f$ be defined? should it be analytic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk? or should it be analytic in the *open* unit disk and continuous on the closed unit disk?

Comment: if it is possible to be analytic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk, that would be great, it is what I had in mind

Answer (score 1):

The key is the simple geometric fact that given any two points $z_1, z_2\in \bar{D}$ there exists a circle $C\subset \bar{D}$ passing through $z_1$ and $z_2$. Let $D'$ denote the disk bounded by $C$. Now, assuming $z_1\ne z_2$ (otherwise, use the constant map) take a Moebius transformation $g: D\to D', g(D)=D'$ (you can use a transformation of the form $z\mapsto az+b$ in this part). Then find another Moebius transformation $h: D'\to D'$  sending $g(-1)\mapsto z_1, g(1)\mapsto z_2$. (It is a very good exercise to show that such $h$ exists, I leave you to work this out.)  Lastly, take $f=h\circ g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, gave me a better idea on what to look for. I have yet no clue on how to find such $h$, let's see how it goes

Comment: @gcar: First find such $h$ in the case of  the extended real line with the upper half-plane playing the role of $D'$: Show that you can map any two (distinct) points to any two (distinct) points on ${\mathbb R}\cup \infty$.